# How can child components communicate in React React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get access to `test1()` from `test2()` or vice versa? I already know I have access to each from the parent thru `ref_to_test1` and `ref_to_test2`. But what about the children components calling functions to each other directly?

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
  console.log(this)
    return (
     <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList ref={'ref_to_test1'}/>
        <CommentForm ref={'ref_to_test2'}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
});
var CommentList = React.createClass({
test1:function(){},
  render: function() {
   console.log(this)
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentList.       
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
test2:function(){},
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentForm">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would be to use a global events system of some kind. There are plenty of simple libraries out there to accomplish this, or you could roll your own easily enough.